# Finding Topology Errors toolbox or extension?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, topology

I do not remember if I add this Topology Errors extension or toolbox to my ArcMap.

I  would like to know more about this toolbox.

This is not the same as the Topology toolbox that comes with the ArcMap

[image: Topology Errors]

Comment: Are you referring to this sample?  http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/CPP_VB6_VBA_VCPP_Doc/COM_Samples_Docs/Geodatabase/Creating_and_Converting_Data/Export_Topology_Errors/5308b3e6-4a0a-4236-97e3-22d1f28b12af.htm

Comment: no that is not that one. This one toolbox must have geodatabase to work with Topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export Topology Errors can be found here http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15535:

> Instances will arise when Topology Error information will need to be
>   shared with a user who does not have access to the Topology. Shape,
>   feature class and Exception information all need to be shared. The
>   Export Errors sample can be used to export Topology Errors and
>   optionally, Exceptions, to Shapefile, Personal or File Geodatabase
>   format. Errors can be exported based on three criteria; shape,
>   Topology Rule type or Topoloy Rule.